# Windows Server 2008 VPN

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, vpn

I have some questions about Windows VPN that I am hoping someone can answer:

1) Is it possible to limit what users can access when connecting via VPN? For example, can I only allow users to access one server in the network?

2) If I want to setup VPN so that it always connects when an internet connection is present, is there a way to disable the connection when a user is inside the LAN?

3) Is Windows VPN secure with special certificates? Just using the default configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Nate Boss covered points 1 and 3, but I'd like to offer an option for point 2.  If you're using Windows 7 Enterprise or above clients and you have Windows Server 2008R2, you can set up DirectAccess.  DirectAccess is a technology that attempts to give mobile users the same experience as working in the office - it is essentially a clientless VPN.

I've never set up or managed DirectAccess (I don't have the resources in my test lab), but I have read about it and it looks like it could be a solution to your 2nd point.  Perhaps another poster can talk about their implementation.

You can find more information here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/dd420463

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes -- See [Routing and Remote Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634%28v=WS.10%29.aspx). A simple way to do it, is to assign DHCP to VPN clients on a new subnet, then only allow that subnet to access the resources you want remote users to see.
2. I have never used that option, I always have users connect when necessary. Maybe someone else knows the answer to that point.
3. When configured correctly, yes. There are options during setup/configuration for what type of encryption to require.